# PHP - Change beginning of an Array

Tags: php, arrays

I'd like to change the beginning of my array in PHP.
Currently I've got:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Bla##
  [1] => Bla##
  [2] => Bla##
  [3] => Bla##
  [4] => Bla##
  [5] => Bla##
```

but I want

```
Array
(
  [6] => Bla##
  [7] => Bla##
  [8] => Bla##
  [9] => Bla##
  [10] => Bla##
  [11] => Bla##
```

I used `array_splice($array, 14, 0, 'Bla##');` to insert a value at a specific index of my array, but if I use this my array starts from 0 and not from 6.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want it to be starting at position 6 and not 0?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the indexes and leave the values the same?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, the values have to stay the same.

Comment: I would love to know why you want to do this?

Comment: And it may help with providing a good answer

Comment: Because it's a piece of code I am adding to an API of mine that is a few thousand rows long. If I would change the start of my array, I have to rewrite the whole API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$shift = 6;
$array = array_combine(range($shift, count($array)+$shift-1), $array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just shift all the array positions forward by 6 0->6, 1->7 etc

```
    $array = [Bla##,Bla##,Bla##,Bla##,Bla##,Bla##];
    $newarray = array();    // Shifted array
    for ($i=0; $i < count($array);$i++) {  
          $newarray[$i+6] = $array[$i];  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk()`:

```
$n = 6;
array_walk($arr, function($value) use (&$x, &$n) {$x[$n] = $value; $n++;});
```

---

[PHP Demo](https://ideone.com/ezF18B)